# How can I insert text into UITextField at the current cursor position?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use the UITextField's "return" key to insert a custom character.  Here's what my UITextFieldDelegate method looks like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField insertText:@"¶"];
    return NO;
}
```

Unfortunately, this only works some of the time:

- "one two|" --> *move cursor* --> "one| two" --> *return* --> "one¶| two" (**OK**)
- "onetwo|" --> *return* --> "onetwo¶|" (**OK**)
- "onetwo|" --> *move cursor* --> "one|two" --> *return* --> "onetwo¶|" (**FAIL**)

In the last case I would have expected "one¶|two".

How do I ensure that the inserted text is always inserted at the cursor position?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you tap the return key on the keyboard, the text field sets the selected range (the cursor position) to the end of its text **before** it sends you the `textFieldShouldReturn:` message.

You need to keep track of the cursor position so you can restore it to its prior position. Let's say you have a reference to the text field in a property:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end
```

You'll need an instance variable to hold the prior selected text range (from before the return key was tapped):

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UITextRange *priorSelectedTextRange_;
}
```

Then you can write a method that saves the selected text range to the instance variable:

```
- (void)saveTextFieldSelectedTextRange {
    priorSelectedTextRange_ = self.textField.selectedTextRange;
}
```

and in `textFieldShouldReturn:`, before you insert the pilcrow, you can change the selected text range back to its prior value:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.selectedTextRange = priorSelectedTextRange_;
    [textField insertText:@"¶"];
    return NO;
}
```

But how can we make the system send the `saveTextFieldSelectedTextRange` message when we need it to?

- The `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol doesn't have messages for changes to the selected range.
- `UITextField` doesn't post any notifications for changes to the selected range.
- The `UITextInputDelegate` protocol does have `selectionWillChange:` and `selectionDidChange:` messages, but the system sets the text field's `inputDelegate` to its own `UIKeyboardImpl` object when the text field begins editing, so we can't use the `inputDelegate`.
- Key-value observing on the text field's `selectedTextRange` property isn't reliable.  In my testing on the iOS 6.0 simulator, I don't get a KVO message when I move the cursor from the middle to the end of the text by tapping the text field.

The only way I can think of to *reliably* track changes to the text field's selected range is by adding an observer to the run loop.  On every pass through the event loop, the observer runs before event processing, so it can grab the current selected range before it changes.

So we actually need another instance variable, to hold the reference to our run loop observer:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UITextRange *priorSelectedTextRange_;
    CFRunLoopObserverRef runLoopObserver_;
}
```

We create the observer in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createRunLoopObserver];
}
```

and we destroy it in both `viewDidUnload` and in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self destroyRunLoopObserver];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self destroyRunLoopObserver];
}
```

To create the observer, we need a plain old C function for it to call.  Here's that function:

```
static void runLoopObserverCallback(CFRunLoopObserverRef observer, CFRunLoopActivity activity, void *info) {
    __unsafe_unretained ViewController *self = (__bridge ViewController *)info;
    [self saveTextFieldSelectedTextRange];
}
```

Now we can actually create the observer and register it with the main run loop:

```
- (void)createRunLoopObserver {
    runLoopObserver_ = CFRunLoopObserverCreate(NULL, kCFRunLoopAfterWaiting, YES, 0, &runLoopObserverCallback, &(CFRunLoopObserverContext){
        .version = 0,
        .info = (__bridge void *)self,
        .retain = CFRetain,
        .release = CFRelease,
        .copyDescription = CFCopyDescription
    });
    CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetMain(), runLoopObserver_, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}
```

and here's how we actually deregister the observer and destroy it:

```
- (void)destroyRunLoopObserver {
    if (runLoopObserver_) {
        CFRunLoopRemoveObserver(CFRunLoopGetMain(), runLoopObserver_, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
        CFRelease(runLoopObserver_);
        runLoopObserver_ = NULL;
    }
}
```

This approach works in my testing on the iOS 6.0 simulator.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.  How do you recommend releasing the run loop observer in an ARC project?

Comment: ARC does not manage Core Foundation objects like `CFRunLoopObserver`. You need the `CFRelease` in `destroyRunLoopObserver` whether using MRC or ARC.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I was seeing an error because I was calling [super dealloc] (not because I was defining a dealloc method).

Comment: You cannot call `[super dealloc]` explicitly under ARC.  ARC always calls `[super dealloc]` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you're not keeping track of the insertion point, also known as the selection range.

And to do that, you need to get somewhat deeper into the guts of what UITextField can do.

[Using UITextInput (accessible as a protocol that UITextField uses)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput), you can fetch the ["`selectedTextRange`" property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/selectedTextRange) which tells you where the caret (cursor, insertion point) is and that's where you should insert your special character.  This *should* work if you set your object to be a delegate that conforms to the "`UITextInput`" protocol.

Comment: Same problem: after entering "onetwo" then moving the cursor to "one|two" the `selectedTextRange`'s start and end values are 6.

Comment: I also found [this interesting blog entry](http://neofight.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/finding-the-cursor-position-in-a-uitextfield/).

Comment: The text field moves the cursor to the end when you tap the return key, *before* it sends the `textFieldShouldReturn:` message, so by the time you receive that message, it's too late to look at `selectedTextRange`.